# solr-4.9.0: how can solrj delete documents in "implicit router" effectively?

Tags: router, solrj, implicit, documents

I used "implicit router" when created my collection and I used SolrJ to access Solr. In this mode, I do my query request by providing a param named *route*。But, if I want to call CloudSolrServer's `deleteByQuery()` method,how can I set this parameter? I just only want to pass my request to the right shard, not all shards, I don't know how to get it。

Answer (score 2):

Luckily,I have founded the answer. When I was reading CloudSolrServer's source code, I founded the following method:

---

```
public UpdateResponse deleteByQuery(String query) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    return new UpdateRequest().deleteByQuery( query ).process( this );
}
```

And the UpdateResponse class has a method setParam().

So, the final code is as follows:

---

```
UpdateRequest deleteRequest = new UpdateRequest();
deleteRequest.setParam("_route_", shardId);
UpdateResponse reponse = deleteRequest.deleteByQuery(delQuery).process(cloudSolrServer_);
```

I have tried it and found no problems.